# R;how to specify different areas according to the max value of several two variable function on x-y plane

Tags: r, ggplot2, draw

I got several functions f1(x,y), f2(x,y), f3(x,y), f4(x,y),
where f1=5x+2y, f2=ylog(x), f3=xy/10, f4=x^3-5y. x and y both range from 0 to 100.
I want to draw different colors on different areas to specify which functions give the max value on the x-y plane. I'm using ggplot. Can anyone help me?

```
f1<-function(x,y)5*x+2*y
f2<-function(x,y)y*log(x)
f3<-function(x,y)x*y/10 
f4<-function(x,y)x^3-5*y
x<-seq(0,100,1);y<-seq(0,100,1)
vmax<-c()
for(i in 1:101){
  v<-c(f1(x[i],y[i]),f2(x[i],y[i]),f3(x[i],y[i]),f3(x[i],y[i]))
  vmax[i]=which.max(v)
}
df<-data.frame(x,y,vmax)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y),vmax)
```

Comment: Could you share a little bit of code? The first step would be to code up your functions in valid R syntax. Have you done that? Could you share it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I edited what I've tried so far. What I need is to label the area in which f1 (f2, f3,f4) gives the max value, and use different colors to specify.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a good start. You've got a problem, which is that you're incrementing `x` and `y` at the same time, so you evaluate your functions at points (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), ..., but never (1, 2), (2, 1), etc.

You've also got an inefficiency in that all your functions are vectorized, so the can be evaluated on a vector of points all at once.

Here I use `expand.grid` to generate all possible combinations of the input `x` and `y` values, and then we can evaluate each function on the whole set at once:

```
df = expand.grid(x = 0:10, y = 0:10)
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(
  f1 = f1(x, y),
  f2 = f2(x, y),
  f3 = f3(x, y),
  f4 = f4(x, y)
)

f_cols = paste0("f", 1:4)
df$fmax = factor(apply(df[f_cols], 1, \(val) f_cols[which.max(val)]), levels = f_cols)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = fmax)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

As you can see I only set `x` and `y` to go from 0 to 10, but you can scale that up as much as you'd like.

Comment: I  got an error running the code, could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: > df$fmax = factor(apply(df[f_cols], 1, \(val) f_cols[which.max(val)]), levels = f_cols)
Error: unexpected input in "df$fmax = factor(apply(df[f_cols], 1, \"

Comment: If you are using R version less than 4.1, replace `\(val)` with `function(val)`.